# How can I avoid exceeding the internal ILK size limit in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, linker

Building a large project in Visual Studio 2005, I am getting an error in incremental linking:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1210: exceeded internal ILK size limit; link with /INCREMENTAL:NO

Do you know of any options other than avoiding incremental linking?  In particular, are there practices that will reduce the size of the internal ILK data?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  /LTCG flag to the linker

Answer (score 1):

/LTCG is not valid for use with /INCREMENTAL according to MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

first end up all useless processes (firefox, it likes RAM), close VS and wait a while, relunch IDE, only IDE and try build. didnt help - try release build. still error - edit boot.ini there is the limit specified.